# Diagnosing issues with the system(command) call?

Tags: c++, c

I have an application that at some point calls

```
system("/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat F")
```

to flush the ip tables. Since the application is multi threaded and developed by multiple developers, at some point the iptables stopped being set. It turned out that I'm not able to lunch external processes (have also tried `system("/bin/ls")` without success). The commands can be run from the shell with no issues.

I get the return value `-1` regardless of the command called. Is there a way to get some more information on why this is failing?

Comment: is your app started with sudo?

Comment: It's a single user (root) embedded device. 
Good remark though.

Comment: Have a look at errno. Might give you more details.

Comment: First, check the result of `system(NULL)`.

Comment: @Oncaphillis Yes, got the `Cannot allocate memory`. That's a message to work with. Will accept the answer if you post it.

Comment: What does "this function got lost" even mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try printing out the `errorno` or its descriptive string after the `system` call. Add the following:

```
#include <errno.h>

system("/bin/ls");
printf ("Error: %s\n",strerror(errno));
```

Might give you more details.

Comment: Also make sure to *clear* `errno` before `system()`.